# Python Thread problems

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to make a program that does this:

1. Calls program 1 in a thread
2. Calls program 2 in another thread
3. If program 1 ends first, kill program 2, or vice-versa.

I've been trying for a long time and these are my current problem:

1. I can't import Thread module (not threading!).
2. Function or Class, that is the question.

I already know how to call the processes using subprocess.Popen and how to kill them usign a command line function. I also know how to get the PID.

Here's my actual code:

```
import threading, subprocess, shlex

class Prog1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, arg=''):
        self.arg = arg
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        p = subprocess.Popen(shelx.split(self.arg))
        global p.pid
        subprocess.Popen(shelx.split("kill -9 " + q.pid))


class Prog2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, arg=''):
        self.arg = arg
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        q = subprocess.Popen(shelx.split(self.arg))
        global q.pid
        subprocess.Popen(shelx.split("kill -9 " + p.pid))
```

Comment: Welcome to this site! We'd like to help you, but this is not possible without more information about what you have tried, and precisely where you got stuck. Showing us your code would help. Try to make up a minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To kill all processes if any of them has exited you could call [`process.wait()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) for each process in a separate thread and use [`threading.Event`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/threading#event-objects) to signal if any of the processes ended:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import shlex
import subprocess
import threading


def kill_all(processes):
    for p in processes:
        try:
            if p.poll() is None:
                p.kill()  # note: it may leave orphans
                p.wait()
        except:  # pylint: disable=W0702
            pass  # ignore whatever it is (including SIGINT)


def wait(process, exit_event):
    try:
        process.wait()
    finally:
        exit_event.set()  # signal the process has exited


def main():
    # start processes
    cmd = "/bin/bash -c 'echo start {0}; sleep {0}; echo done {0}'".format
    processes = []
    for i in range(1, 3):
        try:
            processes.append(subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd(i))))
        except EnvironmentError:
            kill_all(processes)  # failed to start some process; kill'em all
            return 1  # error

    # wait until at least one process finishes
    exit_event = threading.Event()
    for p in processes:
        threading.Thread(target=wait, args=(p, exit_event)).start()

    exit_event.wait()
    kill_all(processes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

#### Output

```
start 1
start 2
done 1
```

Answer (score 2):

on python 2.7

```
import thread
```

then

```
thread.start_new_thread(funct,(param1, param2...))
```

works for me, don't know about killing them, but from your question, this is what you're stuck on?

after feedback from @J.F.Sebastian I started researching the new(old) threading module and to fix my earlier code, and the code I'm currently working on.

```
import threading

t=threading.Thread(target=fuct, args=(param1, param2...)).start()
```

don't know if this is the most robust way to use it, but I've only known it existed for 25 mins :)

Comment: `thread` module is [obsolete](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3108/#obsolete).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian  what is the new standard? I don't keep overly up to date, just googling when stuck and seeing what works.